# How to iterate through a list of dictionaries, take the value of a condition and add it to a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-lists

So I got a big list with dictionaries inside it. Here is a small example of one of the dictionaries:

```
[{'id': 32,
'calls': 1,
'wounded': 2,
'dog': True,
'hitrun': 'David Williams'},
{'id': 384,
```

I want to iterate through these dictionaries, get the value of calls and wounded if they're bigger than 0 and add these values to a new list. I tried doing this:

```
lijst = []
for x in nee:
if x['calls'] > '0':
    list.append(x)
if x['wounded'] > '0':
    list.append(x)
```

But this doesn't work. There are also some calls and wounded with None as their value, so the > 0 doesn't work either

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?  What is `c` in `list.append(c)`? Do both values have to be g.t. zero. If the values meet the criteria does the complete dictionary get appended to the *new* list?

Comment: I get this error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. I think the c is wrong. it should be x instead. Both values have to be bigger than zero, but there's also another problem: some of these values are None so it gives another error

Comment: Your example dictionary values are `ints` and your conditional statement values are strings. Try `if float(x['calls'] > 0:...` and `if float(x['wounded'] > 0:...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension, because you need to iterate over your data and your conditions, for example, something like this:

```py
data = [
    {'id': 32,
    'calls': '1',
    'wounded': '2',
    'dog': True,
    'hitrun': 'David Williams'},
    {'id': 32,
    'calls': None,
    'wounded': None,
    'dog': True,
    'hitrun': 'David Williams'}
]

output = [
    x[field] for x in data for field in ['calls', 'wounded'] if x[field] is not None and int(x[field]) > 0
]

print(output)
>>> ['1', '2']
```

Comment: I get this error and can't seem to fix it: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @taaaaavi that's because you can't compare `string` elements with `integer` ones using `>`, I updated the answer to solve that.

Comment: Thankyou! This dataset is really problematic though, there are also some Nones in it so now I get this: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'. I don't know how I can delete these Nones?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
nee = [{'id': 32,
'calls': 1,
'wounded': 2,
'dog': True,
'hitrun': 'David Williams'}]

l = []
for x in nee:
  if x['calls'] > 0:
    l.append(x['calls'])
  if x['wounded'] > 0:
    l.append(x['wounded'])

print(l)
```

You can also sum two list comprehensions:

```
wounded = [x['wounded'] for x in nee if x['wounded'] > 0]
calls = [x['calls'] for x in nee if x['calls'] > 0]
new_list = wounded + calls
print(new_list)
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will have another solution using `itertools` or nested list comprehension.

Comment: I tried something like this too, but then I get this error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. Then I tried making the int 0 to a '0' but that didn't work either

Comment: The 0 should not be a string

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
data = [
    {'id': 32,
    'calls': '1',
    'wounded': '2',
    'dog': True,
    'hitrun': 'David Williams'},
    {'id': 32,
    'calls': None,
    'wounded': None,
    'dog': True,
    'hitrun': 'David Williams'}
]
call_wounded_list = [dict_[f] for dict_ in data for f in ['calls', 'wounded'] if str(dict_[f]).isdigit() and float(dict_[f]) > 0]
```

this returns

```
>>> call_wounded_list
['1', '2']
```